# Google Sheets Script - find/replace - find lower and uppercase words, exact match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using a script that finds/replaces words `onEdit`. However, it does not work on words that are capitalized (my find query is lower case). How can I get it to match both the upper and lowercase words that are an exact match?

Example: 
find: "sun" and "Sun"
replace: "sunshine" (lowercase only)

Also, I do NOT want it to replace partial words
Example:
find: "sun" and "Sun" exact string -- not "sunny" or "sung" or "sundry"

Appreciate any help you can provide!

My script:

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("pss");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:J" + lr);
  var vlst = range.getValues();

  range.setValues(vlst);
  var i,j,a,find,repl;
   for (var i = 0; i < vlst.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < vlst[i].length; j++){
      a = vlst[i][j];
      if (a == find) vlst[i][j] = repl; 
    find ="sun";
    repl ="sunshine";
    }
  }
```

Comment: `var vlst = range.getValues(); } }` These 3 lines really change the meaning of your script. I suggest you highlight all your code in your script editor, press Tab (to automatically indent based on syntax), and then fix the issues you find so that the code matches your intent.

Comment: As it is, your code doesn't make any sense... please consider rewrite it properly. It looks like you put some pieces together without caring about the order.

Comment: @tehhowch, apologies- i copied my script wrong (adding the 4 spaces before the script confused me). i edited my question to include the correct script. would you mind taking a look at the corrected script and tell me how to make sure it will include capitalized or lowercase queries? thank you :)

Comment: @I'-'I, i looked into regex, but it seemed a bit complicated (esp for a noob like me). I have multiple queries, this is just one of 10. all 10 run perfectly fine, except they don't include the capitalized versions. the long solution is to just add `find = "Sun";` `repl = "sunshine"` but to add 10 more of these just seems excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

- Improper ordering of statements &syntax:

  - setValues() should be used after replacing all values(NOT before).
  - find/repl variables should be declared and initialized before the `if` statement(Though it works for subsequent loops due to hoisting/scoping).
  - Missing `}`
- Case Insensitive find and replace

#### Solution:

- Reorder and initialize variables before execution[⁰](https://www.w3schools.com/js).
- Use objects[¹](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) to store key/value pairs.
- Use `toLowerCase()`[²](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on find variable.
- Alternatively, use event objects[³](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) instead of looping through everything.

#### Modified Script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("pss");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:J" + lr);
  var vlst = range.getValues();
  var findReplace = { //FindReplace object storing key/value pairs in lowercase
    'sun': 'sunshine',
    'moon': 'moonlight',
    'evil': 'evil MasterMind'
  };
  var i, j, a;
  for (i = 0; i < vlst.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < vlst[i].length; j++) {
      a = vlst[i][j].toString().toLowerCase();
      if (findReplace[a]) vlst[i][j] = findReplace[a];
    }
  }

  range.setValues(vlst); //Moved below
}//Added
```

#### Script#2

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var findReplace = {
    'sun': 'sunshine',
    'moon': 'moonlight',
    'evil': 'evil MasterMind'
  },
    a = findReplace[e.value.toString().toLowerCase()];
  if (a) e.range.setValue(a);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! the modified script worked amazingly well! it makes my script much less verbose (thank you) and finds both the lowercase/uppercase queries and matches the exact word (not replacing `sun` in `sunny` >> `sunshineny`). the `Script#2` you also offered gave me an error on this line: `var findReplace = {` showing this error message: `Cannot read property "value" from undefined`. Do I need `Script#2` or will it work fine with just the `Modified Script`? It seems to work perfectly without, but I defer to your expertise. Thank you again!!!

Comment: @|`-`|, for some reason it won't run, but no worries. the first script you provided works perfectly. thank you so much :)

Comment: nope, just one `onEdit` script. i can save the `onEdit(e)` script, but can't run it. Same error message, says it `Cannot read property "value" from undefined` referencing line  `var findReplace = {`.  i tried adding the same beginning as the first script you provided: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("pss");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:J" + lr);
  var vlst = range.getValues();
  var findReplace = {` but still got the same error message. Does it need a `.getValues()` at the end of `var findReplace'?

Comment: i only have 2 scripts: the `onOpen` to sort and then the `onEdit` to find/replace (which works awesome btw). do i need the `onEdit(e)`? the 1st script didn't change previous cells that contained "Sun" so I went in and manually changed all of them. is that what this `onEdit(e)` script is supposed to do?

Comment: i deleted `onEdit` and put in `onEdit(e)` only. Saved it but didn't run it. It works! Just curious, why is `onEdit(e)` better than the `onEdit` script? They both worked fine, although the `onEdit(e)` is more elegant (and shorter)